# PaperClip No handler found Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I have 2 models `Products` and `ProductImage`. `Product has_many ProductImages`. I am using paperclip gem.

When i submit the `Product Form` i get this error.

```
No handler found for ["0", {"product_image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8cb78b29c8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/yx/znmx6qfj0c507bvkym6lvhxh0000gn/T/RackMultipart20151221-46388-dqxfk7.jpg>, @original_filename="780069_black_l.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[product_images_attributes][0][product_image]\"; filename=\"780069_black_l.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}]

  def create_product_images
    params["product"]["product_images_attributes"].each do |image|
      ProductImage.create(product_image: image, product_id: @form.product.id)
    end
  end
```

**Anyone know how to fix this? Im trying to create a ProductImage. So when i go product.product_images i have an array of all the images for the product.**

Here is the form

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "custom" %>
<div class="container">
  <div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= simple_form_for @product do |f| %>
            <%= f.fields_for :product_images do |product_image| %>
              <% if product_image.object.new_record? %>
                <%= product_image.file_field(:product_image) %>
              <% else %>
                <%= image_tag(product_image.url(:thumb)) %>
                <%= product_image.hidden_field :_destroy %>
                <%= product_image.link_to_remove "X" %>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
            <%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, :name, include_blank: true, prompt: "Select One Category" %>
            <% @categories.each do |category| %>
              <div class='sizes_container' id ='sizes_container_for_<%= category.id %>'>
                <% category.sizes.each do |size| %>
                  <%= label_tag "product_form[sizes_by_id][#{size.id}]", size.title %>
                  <%= text_field_tag "product_form[sizes_by_id][#{size.id}]" %>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            <% end %>
            <%= f.input :title, label:"Title"%>
            <%= f.input :price, label:"Price"%>
            <%= f.input :description,label:"Description" %>
            <%= f.input :size_description, label:"Size Details"%>
            <%= f.input :shipping_description, label:"Shipping Details"%>
            <%= f.input :tag_list,label:"Tags - Seperate tags using comma ','. 5 tags allowed per product" %>
            <%= f.button :submit, "Create new product", class: "btn-lg btn-success" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what the params look like

```
    69: def create_product_images
    70:   params["product"]["product_images_attributes"].each do |image|
 => 71:     binding.pry
    72:     ProductImage.create(product_image: image, product_id: @form.product.id)
    73:   end
    74: end

[1] pry(#<ProductsController>)> params["product"]["product_images_attributes"]
=> {"0"=>
  {"product_image"=>
    #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8cacd89b28
     @content_type="image/jpeg",
     @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[product_images_attributes][0][product_image]\"; filename=\"780069_black_l.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
     @original_filename="780069_black_l.jpg",
     @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/yx/znmx6qfj0c507bvkym6lvhxh0000gn/T/RackMultipart20151221-46388-d4pub9.jpg>>},
 "1"=>
  {"product_image"=>
    #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8cacd897b8
     @content_type="image/jpeg",
     @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[product_images_attributes][1][product_image]\"; filename=\"20090a.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
     @original_filename="20090a.
```

Product Controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:edit, :show, :update]
  before_action :correct_user_edit,   only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @categories = Category.preload(:sizes).order(:name)
    @product.product_images.build
  end

  def home
    @products = Product.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def show
  end

  def update
    if @product.update(product_params)
       redirect_to @product
       flash[:success] = 'Item was successfully updated.'
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def create
    @form = ProductForm.new(
      product_image: product_params[:product_image],
      title: product_params[:title],
      price: product_params[:price],
      size_description: product_params[:size_description],
      shipping_description: product_params[:shipping_description],
      description: product_params[:description],
      tag_list: product_params[:tag_list],
      category_id: product_params[:category_id],
      sizes_by_id: product_params[:sizes_by_id],
      user: current_user
    )
    if @form.save
      create_product_images
      redirect_to @form.product
      flash[:success] = "You have created a new product"
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Your product didn't save"
      new
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Product deleted"
    redirect_to user_products_path
  end

  private

  def create_product_images
    params["product"]["product_images_attributes"].each do |index, image|
      ProductImage.create(product_image: image, product_id: @form.product.id)
    end
  end

  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(
        :product_images_attributes,
        :title,
        :price,
        :description,
        :tag_list,
        :category_id,
        :size_description,
        :shipping_description,
      ).merge(sizes_by_id: params[:product_form][:sizes_by_id]) # TODO
  end

  def correct_user_edit
    if @product = current_user.products.find_by(id: params[:id])
    else
      redirect_to root_url if @product.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

product_form.rb

```
class ProductForm
  attr_reader :quantity_by_size_id, :product

  def initialize(product_image:, title:, price:, description:, tag_list:, category_id:, sizes_by_id:, user:, size_description:, shipping_description:)
    @quantity_by_size_id = sizes_by_id # TODO
    @product_images = product_image
    @product = Product.new(
      title: title,
      price: price,
      description: description,
      tag_list: tag_list,
      category_id: category_id,
      size_description: size_description,
      shipping_description: shipping_description,
      user: user
    )
    build_product_sizes
  end

  def save
    product.save
  end

  private

  def build_product_sizes
    quantity_by_size_id.map do |size_id, quantity|
      if quantity.to_i.nonzero?
        product.product_sizes.build(product: product, size_id: size_id, quantity: quantity)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category

  has_many :product_sizes
  has_many :product_images, :dependent => :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 2000 }
  validates :category, :user, :price, presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images, allow_destroy: true
end
```

schema

```
  create_table "product_sizes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.integer "size_id"
  end
```

product_size.rb

```
class ProductSize < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :size

  validates :quantity, presence: true
end
```

params

```
From: /Users/jo/Documents/Safsy/Website/Safsy/Safsy/app/controllers/products_controller.rb @ line 36 ProductsController#create:

    35: def create
 => 36:   binding.pry
    37:   @form = ProductForm.new(
    38:     product_image: product_params[:product_image],
    39:     title: product_params[:title],
    40:     price: product_params[:price],
    41:     size_description: product_params[:size_description],
    42:     shipping_description: product_params[:shipping_description],
    43:     description: product_params[:description],
    44:     tag_list: product_params[:tag_list],
    45:     category_id: product_params[:category_id],
    46:     sizes_by_id: product_params[:sizes_by_id],
    47:     user: current_user
    48:   )
    49:   if @form.save
    50:     create_product_images
    51:     redirect_to @form.product
    52:     flash[:success] = "You have created a new product"
    53:   else
    54:     flash[:danger] = "Your product didn't save"
    55:     new
    56:     render "new"
    57:   end
    58: end

[1] pry(#<ProductsController>)> params
=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"3MZESoSUgrO2Bc3vl8/M0pTfTna9rjeXfXG23znsy3VGCEBcHMh+4ZC5rqSxGkQOmz4kl1JN9FFMH4lniDjFQg==",
 "product"=>
  {"product_images_attributes"=>
    {"0"=>
      {"product_image"=>
        #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8c9ceb22f8
         @content_type="image/jpeg",
         @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[product_images_attributes][0][product_image]\"; filename=\"780069_black_l.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
         @original_filename="780069_black_l.jpg",
         @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/yx/znmx6qfj0c507bvkym6lvhxh0000gn/T/RackMultipart20151222-46388-pgfg4b.jpg>>,
       "_destroy"=>"false"},
     "1450783221367"=>
      {"product_image"=>
        #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8c9ceb2140
         @content_type="image/jpeg",
         @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[product_images_attributes][1450783221367][product_image]\"; filename=\"20090a.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
         @original_filename="20090a.jpg",
         @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/yx/znmx6qfj0c507bvkym6lvhxh0000gn/T/RackMultipart20151222-46388-3vamt4.jpg>>,
       "_destroy"=>"false"}},
   "category_id"=>"3",
   "title"=>"new product",
   "price"=>"352.40",
   "description"=>"test",
   "size_description"=>"test",
   "shipping_description"=>"test",
   "tag_list"=>"test"},
 "product_form"=>{"sizes_by_id"=>{"1"=>"3", "2"=>"34", "3"=>""}},
 "commit"=>"Create new product",
 "controller"=>"products",
 "action"=>"create"}
[2] pry(#<ProductsController>)> product_params
Unpermitted parameter: product_images_attributes
=> {"title"=>"new product",
 "price"=>"352.40",
 "description"=>"test",
 "tag_list"=>"test",
 "category_id"=>"3",
 "size_description"=>"test",
 "shipping_description"=>"test",
 "sizes_by_id"=>{"1"=>"3", "2"=>"34", "3"=>""}}
[3] pry(#<ProductsController>)>
```

Update

After trying Rich Peck's answer i have the product images persisting and product.product_images is now working

My product_params look like this.

```
  def product_params
     params.require(:product).permit(
      :title,
      :price,
      :description,
      :tag_list,
      :category_id,
      :size_description,
      :shipping_description,
      product_images_attributes: [:product_image, :_destroy],
      product_sizes_attributes: [:size_id, :quantity]
    )
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you looping through your params and performing a `create` method?

--

You should just be able to pass the `images` through to your nested model with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`:

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :product_images
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images, allow_destroy: true
end

#app/models/product_image.rb
class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
   has_attached_file :product_image
end
```

This should pass the nested image object from your `@product` form to your `ProductImage` model.

As long as you permit the right parameters, it should work fine for you:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @product = Product.new 
      @product.product_images.build
   end

   def create
      @product = Product.new product_params
      @product.save
   end

   private

   def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:product, :params, product_images_attributes: [:product_image] %>
   end
end
```

Your form looks okay.

---

**Update**

Okay, in regards to saving `ProductSize` along with the image, you can use `accetps_nested_attributes_for` to save them at the same time...

I would always advocate using this instead of trying to create your own classes in an `after_create` call or whatever -- keeping the flow consistent is the most important thing you can do.

Anyway...

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :product_images
   has_many :product_sizes
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images, :product_sizes
end

#app/models/product_size.rb
class ProductSize < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
end

#app/models/product_image.rb
class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
   has_attached_image :image
end
```

This will allow you to use the following controller setup:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @product = Product.new
      @product.product_images.build
      @product.product_sizes.build
   end

   def create
      @product = Product.new product_params
      @product.save
   end

   private

   def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:x, :y, :z, product_images_attributes: [:image], product_sizes_attributes: [:a, :b, :c])
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use a similar setup to what you have currently:

```
#app/views/products/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :product_images do |p| %>
      <%= p.file_field :image %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.fields_for :product_sizes do |s| %>
      <%= s.text_field :a %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to use all the validations you require etc, *and* if you use [`Cocoon`](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), you'll be able to add extra sizes as you require.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this today.

Comment: Hello Rich. I had a look into this. And pretty sure it won't work like that. Its because i have a very complex form an using a Form Object to create the Product and ProductSizes. Now im trying to create the ProductImage. So when i go product.product_images i get a list of images for that product. I have added my Product Controller and ProductForm.

Comment: Looks like a standard form to me, why are you complicating it so much?

Comment: I thought i couldnt do it normally. I added my Product model and ProductSize model. The user comes to the form. Selects which images to upload, the selects what category, If its Shirts a list of shirt sizes will drop down and next to each size they can put in a quantity, then they fill out the rest of the form. Its all working excepts images.

Comment: Where did `ProductSize` come from? Is the image model dependent on the size model?

Comment: Ive added product_size.rb to the question. I have the schema for it too. Its so i can store the quantity for each size of the product.

Comment: Why are you calling the custom `ProductForm` object? Why not just use a standard form?

Comment: Because at the same time as creating a Product I need to create a ProductSize for each size that has a quantity. If the user choses Shirt as the category and they have 9 XS(id:4) shirts and 11 Large shirts i need to create 2 ProductSizes. ProductSize.create(quanitity: 9, product_id:?, size_id: 4). Do you think i should do accepts_nested_attributes: ProductSizes in the Product model and drop the ProductForm and just go on the create action Product.new(product_params)?

Comment: Yes I do - you can create the appropriate product_sizes off the back of the form submit. I'll write an update in a minute if you want

Comment: Ok lets do it. I will wait for your update. Thanks so much Rich!

Comment: I have added what the params look when the create action is hit incase it helps.

Comment: Thanks bud, just fixing something; will get back in a second

Comment: Thank you so much. I will take a look today. Im just at work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It was a pleasure working with you. This form has taken me a long time to make. Incase you're interested theres a continuation of problem with this form. Its not creating the ProductSizes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433155/nested-form-not-creating-the-record-thats-nested

Comment: O yes it does. product.product_images works now. Thats why i posted another question because it doesn't relate to this. Thank you Rich.

Comment: Nice, glad it helped you out

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an Array, it seems a Hash there.

Your Hash looks like `{"ID" => IMAGE}`

Try to iterate over an id and image like this:

```
params["product"]["product_images_attributes"].each do |index, image|
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this today.